# Webos Mojo palm-group change border color and width

Tags: webos, mojo

Does anyone know what css is needed to change the border color, width and radius of a WebOS Mojo palm-group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for labeled group

```
.palm-group {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;                                         
    border-width: 40px 18px 18px 18px;                              
    -webkit-border-image: url(../images/palm-group.png) 40 18 18 18;
    }
```

for unlabeled groups :

```
.palm-group.unlabeled {
border-width: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
-webkit-border-image: url(../images/palm-group-unlabeled.png) 18 18 18 18;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.